# How to unnest JSON with levels upon levels

Tags: python, arrays, json, nested-lists, unnest

I'm trying to unnest a json file. The JSON has multiple lists of dictionaries inside a list of dictionaries. I'm trying to flatten everything in it and turn it into a dataframe. it looks something like this:

```
{
 "Result": [
   {
     "OptionalColumns": {
       "optionalColumnName": "Joe Blogs"
     },
     "fieldOne": "some string",
     "fieldtwo": "some more string",
     "fieldthree": "even more string",
     "secondList": [
       {
         "secondListFieldOne": "value",
         "secondListFieldTwo": 0,
         "secondListFieldThree": true
       },
       {
         "secondListFieldOne": "value",
         "secondListFieldTwo": 0,
         "secondListFieldThree": true
       }
     ],
     "anotherField": "string value",
     "thirdList": [
       {
         "thirdListFieldOne": "string",
         "thirdListFieldTwo": "string"
       }
     ],
     "someNumberValue": 1
   },
   {
     "OptionalColumns": {
       "optionalColumnName": "Joe Blogs"
     },
     "fieldOne": "some string",
     "fieldtwo": "some more string",
     "fieldthree": "even more string",
     "secondList": [
       {
         "secondListFieldOne": "value",
         "secondListFieldTwo": 0,
         "secondListFieldThree": true
       },
       {
         "secondListFieldOne": "value",
         "secondListFieldTwo": 0,
         "secondListFieldThree": true
       }
     ],
     "anotherField": "string value",
     "thirdList": [
       {
         "thirdListFieldOne": "string",
         "thirdListFieldTwo": "string"
       }
      ],
      "someNumberValue": 1
    }
  ],
  "Message": null,
  "Errors": []
}
```

I'm using the below method to unnest. I know this works with one nest, or even two, however I can't for the life of me get it to work. HELP.

```
with open('data/my_file.json','r') as f:
    json_data = json.loads(f.read())

df_unnested_list = pd.json_normalize(json_data, 'Result')
```

When trying to unnest a list of dicts:

```
pd.json_normalize(data, "field", ["fieldTwo", "nestFieldOne"])
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be how you posted it before with another dict. Quite simple really.

```
pd.json_normalize(data, “thirdList”, [“OptionalColumns”, “optionalColumnName”],”fieldOne”, “fieldTwo”, “fieldThree”, [“secondList”, “secondListDictOneFieldOne”,”secondListDictTwoFieldOne”], “anotherField”, “someNumberValue”)
```

Comment: I tried this, it didnt work unfortunately.